# Remove Object From Array with Specific Requirement

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a custom object `Shift`

```
struct Shift: Identifiable, Encodable, Equatable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var weekday: String
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date
}
```

And an array of `Shift` objects:

```
@Published var shifts: [Shift] = []
```

I would like to remove the last item in the array where the value of `weekday` is equal to `"Monday"`

I tried this but it throws an error saying `Value of type 'Array<Shift>.Index' (aka 'Int') has no member 'removeLast'`

```
if let index = shifts.firstIndex(where: {$0.weekday == "Monday"}) {
    index.removeLast()
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You need [lastIndex(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/lastindex(where:)) and [remove(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/remove(at:)/)

Comment: @vadian Would you please show me how to do it? I have added an example of my attempt above but it throws an error

Comment: The issue is about `index.removeLast()` line, you get the index. Use `shifts.remove(at: index)`. That's what the compiler error says. For the expected result, use `lastIndex(where:)` instead of `firstIndex(where:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you want the **last** index and you want to remove the item from the `shifts` array rather than from the `index`

```
if let index = shifts.lastIndex(where: {$0.weekday == "Monday"}) {
    shifts.remove(at: index)
}
```